# Xcode 8.2 can't find header files from added search path?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am having trouble getting Xcode to find opencv header files. In the 'Build Settings' tab I added the recursive path '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/include' to 'Header Search Paths' and 'User Header Search Paths' and I have an include of `#include "opencv2/core.hpp"`
I added the path to both keys because it wasn't working for either one individually so that's just the way I have it right now. The error I get is `'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found`. Any suggestions? I'm pretty sure this should be working.

EDIT 1: I also have the key 'Always Search User Paths' set to 'Yes'

Answer (score 0):

My apologies to those who spent time trying to figure out what was wrong. The problem was that I had set the build settings for the UI tests target rather than the application project.
In case others come across the same mistake, This is where the target can be changed:[image]
I don't remember ever changing it in the first place, but apparently I did at some point.

Hopefully this is helpful to the next guy that makes this simple mistake.